# how can I hide a widget that generated a signal in qt

Tags: qt, hide, signals, qwidget, generated

Let's say we have more than one widgets and all of them have main menu button. so I connected all of the main menu buttons clicked signal to one slot, which is supposed to h

```
connect(widget1->mainMenuButton, SIGNAL(clicked()),this, SLOT(mainClicked()));
connect(widget1->mainMenuButton, SIGNAL(clicked()),this, SLOT(mainClicked()));
```

and I have

```
private slots:
    void mainClicked();
```

in mainClicked I want to hide whoever triggered the clicked signal. frame1 or frame2 in the above example.

I could use sender() to retrieve the QObject that triggered the signal but then how can I call hide which is QWidget function?

your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
dynamic_cast<QWidget*>(sender()) -> hide() ;
```

Comment: thx I did this QObject *caller = sender()->parent();      ((QWidget*)caller)->hide(); because the sender would be the child of the widget

Comment: qobject_cast<QWidget *>(sender())->window()->hide(); if you want to hide whole window of sender

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `QSignalMapper` class. Basically you connect your two widget's `clicked()` signal to the `map()` slot of the signal mapper and it emits a single `mapped(QWidget*)` signal, that you connect to your `mainClicked(QWidget*)` slot and you get the widget passed, that emited the `clicked` signal (actually you can configure the parameter yourself). The Qt documentation can tell you more.